# Multiple notification in same device GCM

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrate the GCM in ios application, Now i am facing the issue that i am getting the multiple push notification in same device but the server sending only one notification but the device receiving it duplicates.

I have subscribed for topics in GCM and when i am logging out i am removing subscription for that topic.

I have some reasons for that in my mind:

One thing i have register for subscription in GCM ,but without unsubscribing i am deleting the application.

Second thing i have register for subscription in GCM ,and somehow i am not able to unsubscribe when try to logout from the application.

Any helpful answer can be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in GCM iOS SDK version `1.1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I would like to understand why this is happening.

To fix it, I run this code

```
[self.gcmService teardown];
[self.gglInstance stopAllRequests];
[self.gglInstance deleteIDWithHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

But the origin of the problem is unknown, like how to detect this situation in code.

Comment: If you run this code after that do you able to get any notification? As i want to get single notification instead multiple notification.
Are you getting me?

Comment: After this code runs, no more notifications came to the device. Then you need to re-register the device again and subscribe to your topics in order to receive notifications again.

Comment: May be you are right but is that correct solution do you think?
As it should send only one notification.

Comment: In my opinion, this issue is related to the development so I don't think it will happens in production. This is why this code is a workaround to "clear" the situation for the device.

Comment: I'm getting duplicate messages too. In my case, it seems to occur after an uninstall. There's an extra duplicate message after every uninstall. Any ideas why this happens, and what can be done about it?

Comment: @iht Agree with you because when we uninstall the application we are not unregister our token from gcm that's why we are getting multiple notification. But google have to do some logic for that if the deviceId is same then they have to override the previous token or remove the previous token.

Comment: @jogshardik, is the token overriding function documented somewhere? From what I can see, each time I uninstall I get one more set of duplicate messages every time!

Comment: @iht no there is no document of that kind of function but i think they must have create that kind of logic by gcm team.

Comment: Hi @DrAL3X , did you find a solution?

Comment: @CeccoCQ nothing good enough for fix this issue. Mine is just a workaround for debugging, not something to put in production

Comment: @DrAL3X I've tried with your snippet but without success. I've also opened a issue into the GCM github page (https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/101#issuecomment-141603787). Please, could you explain me where you placed your snippet in iOS code? I need a workaround until Google fixes...

Comment: @CeccoCQ I need to subscribe the app (to GCM) just if some conditions are met. If not, the app should not receive any notification. In my case, if I receive some (with no intentional subscriptions in place), I will clear the gcm id and stuff with that snippet. Again, I was just exploring it as a workaround and it still is for me, just a workaround

Comment: @DrAL3X & @ CeccoCQ.
I have unregister for the topic and try the above code as well but still i am getting notification multiple times.

Comment: @CeccoCQ opened an issue on Google GCM repository on github. They recognized the bug on their side https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/101

Answer (score 0):

if you send notifications to all users and may be some one get 2 notifications while he should only get one do that

Create file on your server with any number say 0 then when you want to send notification send this numebr with it then add one to this number++ to be new number in the next notification same with every new one

In your application add variable and let this variable = the comming variable from the server after add the notification but you need to ask if(number_in_your_service!=server_number) //add notification

any number of notifications you send just one will appear